# access vue js variable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Calling the strike function (after the select) function, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: selected is not defined

```
methods: {
    select: function(event) {
       selected = event.target.id
    },
    strike: function(event) {
        $(selected).toggleClass('strike')
    }
}
```

This works using JavaScript, `document.getElementById(selected).classList.add('strike')` but not JQuery.

How to I define `selected` for jQuery to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to query the DOM again, it'd be better if you save a reference to the actual element:

```js
methods: {
    select: function(event) {
       this.selected = event.target;
    },
    strike: function() {
        $(this.selected).toggleClass('strike');
    }
}
```

If you don't have to support old IE browsers, you can forgo jQuery here completely by using the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property:

```js
methods: {
    select: function(event) {
       this.selected = event.target;
    },
    strike: function() {
        this.selected.classList.toggle('strike');
    }
}
```

Finally, there should be a way to handle all this through Vue's `:class` binding in the template itself. If you'd show us the template, we may help you improve it.

Comment: I like this approach - docs here for classList https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

Because `$()` is expecting a CSS selector string. Add `#` to denote it is an `id`.

```
$("#" + selected).toggleClass('strike')
```